# What is the reason of this behavior of training loss in CONV auto-encoders?

Tags: neural-network, convolutional-neural-network, pytorch, autoencoder, torch

[image]

I don't get Training Loss is steady up to the 7th epochs

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am asking clarifications on why the training loss is steady up to the 7th percentile and only after there, the model starts learning. I've read here (https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/25704/high-constant-training-loss-with-cnn) that the reason could be the dying ReLU problem